# Is $C^0([0,T]\times M) \subset L^1(0,T;L^1(M))$ dense for $M$ a compact Riemannian manifold?

Tags: functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, bochner-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Is $C^0([0,T]\times M) \subset L^1(0,T;L^1(M))$ dense?